# Cannot resolve GoogleMap error Occurred in Android

Tags: android, android-mapview, android-maps-v2

I want to use GoogleMap in my project, I've used these codes before and it works find but now it doesn't work and show the the error that it cannot resolve googleMap

this is my code :

```
public class MapViewDialog {
Activity act;
String url;
private GoogleMap googleMap;
```

and other codes in my activity either ;

```
MapView mMapView = (MapView) dialog.findViewById(R.id.mapView);
```

this is my layout code :

```
 <com.google.android.gms.maps.MapView
    android:id="@+id/mapView"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" />
```

this is my gradle file :

```
    android {
    compileSdkVersion 27

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.persiandesigners.market"
        minSdkVersion 14
        targetSdkVersion 27
    }

    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled true
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.txt'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:27.1.1'
    implementation 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:27.1.1'
    implementation 'com.android.support:cardview-v7:27.1.1'
    implementation 'com.android.support:design:27.1.1'
    implementation ('cn.trinea.android.view.autoscrollviewpager:android-auto-scroll-view-pager:1.1.2') {
        exclude module: 'support-v4'
    }

    implementation 'com.github.bumptech.glide:glide:3.7.0'
    implementation 'com.github.shell-software:fab:1.1.2'
    implementation 'com.alirezaafkar:sundatepicker:2.0.8'
    implementation 'me.dm7.barcodescanner:zxing:1.9'

    implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-maps:16.0.0'
    implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-gcm:16.0.0'
    implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-location:16.0.0'

    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-core:16.0.1'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging:17.3.3'

    implementation 'com.nineoldandroids:library:2.4.0'
    implementation 'com.daimajia.slider:library:1.1.5@aar'
    implementation 'com.squareup.picasso:picasso:2.5.2'
}
```

I've tried every thing, I cleaned the project, rebuild, invalidate but the error is still on

how can I stop this and solve this issue?

this is my manifest :

```
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
package="com.xxx.market"
android:installLocation="auto"

android:versionCode="1"
android:versionName="1">


<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />


<uses-permission
    android:name="com.android.launcher.permission.INSTALL_SHORTCUT" />

<permission
    android:name="com.xxxx.market.permission.MAPS_RECEIVE"
    android:protectionLevel="signature" />

<uses-feature
    android:glEsVersion="0x00020000"
    android:required="true" />


<application
    android:name="com.xxxx.market.ParseApplication"
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme">

    <meta-data
        android:name="com.google.android.maps.v2.API_KEY"
        android:value="MYCODE" />

    <meta-data
        android:name="com.google.android.gms.version"
        android:value="@integer/google_play_services_version" />
```

....

Comment: share your Manifests file

Comment: @Md.ZakirHossain thanks for reply , I attached my manifest

Comment: add     <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" /> and <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="com.google.android.providers.gsf.permission.READ_GSERVICES" />